# associating column with specific content type in document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am very new on sharepoint. I am using sharepoint 2013. I have a document library which has two types of contents (i.e. document, and document set). I have created a column type called "Month". Now i want to associate the column called "Month" with content type document set. By default it associates with both content types. Is there any way to associate column with specific content type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following steps to do it:

1. Enable "Allow management of content type" setting from Library settins -> Advance Settings.
2. Now create new column in library. And make sure "Add to all content types" check box is checked.
3. Once you do this your column will be added in all content types. Now under content type list. Click on document content type.
4. You will see your added column. click on column and you will get remove Button. You need to do this for all content type where you do not want Month column. Now you have your column added to only in needed content type.